# Hadoop JobHistory shows only the failed jobs

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to monitor the jobs for the sample MapReduce application called Find Maximum Temperature in the The Definitive Hadoop book. On the default installation and configuration of Hadoop-2.6, that application works perfectly, i.e. it calculates the yearly maximum temperatures. But after I extended the configurations of mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml like these: (taken from [How do I view my Hadoop job history and logs using CDH4 and Yarn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656138/how-do-i-view-my-hadoop-job-history-and-logs-using-cdh4-and-yarn) and [YARN job history not coming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039100/yarn-job-history-not-coming))

mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name> mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property> 
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
  <value>localhost:10020</value> 
</property>
<property> 
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
  <value>localhost:19888</value> 
</property>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
  <property>
      <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
      <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
     <value>/app-logs</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir-suffix</name>
      <value>logs</value>
  </property>
```

and when I run the same MaxTemperature application, the application finishes fine and it outputs the file called part-r-00000 but it can't be seen on the JobHistory page at localhost:19888. (Meanwhile the other pages at localhost:8042, localhpst:8088 and localhost:50070 work fine)

Is there a way I can see all the jobs, as they are running on any Hadoop page?

Sometimes when I run the same application, it gives this error:

> 17/09/19 11:07:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :
>   attempt_1505767853223_0003_m_000005_1, Status : FAILED Container
>   launch failed for container_1505767853223_0003_01_000013 :
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The
>   auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:369)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

and if it gives this error, it shows up at the JobHistory page. I have no idea why it sometimes fails, but it occurs after a new start of Hadoop: **start-dfs.sh** and **start-yarn.sh** and the **/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver** 
Here is a SS after 3 jobs failed as such: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search for the *org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist* returned this SO post
[org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345262/org-apache-hadoop-yarn-exceptions-invalidauxserviceexception-the-auxservicemap)

Adding those lines to configuration in yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
```

solved the problem. Now all jobs, whether failed or succeeded come up at the JobHistory page. Here's an SS:

[image]